# Are cookies stored in browser cache?

Tags: javascript, caching, cookies, session-cookies

I'm running into a problem where Javascript I've written is getting an outdated cookie value. Each request made to the server should be updating the cookie with a the date the session will expire. But occasionally the date is in the past (which doesn't make sense because the page just loaded which renews the session).

So I'm wondering if the outdated value could be coming from the browser (Chrome) cache. Do cookie values get stored in the cache and then placed in document.cookie when the cached resource is utilized?

I'm reading the cookie via this code:

```
readCookie : function(name) {
        var match = document.cookie.match(new RegExp("(^|;\\s*)(" + name + ")=([^;]*)"));
        return (match ? decodeURIComponent(match[3]) : null);
    },
```

Comment: You are trying to modify a session cookie with javascript?

Comment: The server is the one updating the cookie with the session expiration date. I'm only reading it on the client.

Comment: So this is likely a question related to server-side code as the server is sending the headers to set the session cookie (and probably other cookies as well unless you are setting cookies in javascript).